# Office install script for OSX

Tags: mac

Apologies if this has already been covered.

I am looking for a script example that will help install Office 2016 for Mac from a local file share.  I will use an MDM tool to assist with the running of the script.  Many Thanks

Comment: It's a bit unclear as to what you want to do.  Can you expand?  The Office 2016 installation is in and of itself, a *script*.

Comment: @John Did my script answer your question (if so, why not mark it as the answer so that people can see it in the future) or were there any problems with it?